# Parse CSV file with commas inside fields

Tags: python, regex, perl, parsing, module

I just received a file from a colleague and don't know how to parse this:

Input:

```
key,value1,"value2,hello"
```

Desired output:

```
key,value2
```

Perl or Python are the languages I understand.

Thanks, Bernardo

Comment: What have you tried so far ? What tools are you using ? Looks like `awk` or `sed` could do that quite easily, have you tried using them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard Perl module [Text::ParseWords](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::ParseWords) can be used to handle CSV files.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::ParseWords;

while (<DATA>) {
  my @fields = parse_line(',', 0, $_);

  # Do something useful with the data in @fields
  print join ' | ', @fields;
}
__DATA__
key,value1,"value2,hello"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is [valid CSV syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), so you can just use a CSV parser.

You did not specify which language you are using, but most have a CSV parser readily available in the class library (for example, [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) in .NET) or as an external component (for example, [CSVParser](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html) in Apache Commons for Java).

If you *do* want to re-invent the wheel (which I do not recommend), the algorithm is quite simple:

```
result = "", inQuotes = false
read next character
if end-of-line:
    if inQuotes:
        throw error (unmatched quotes)
    yield result
    return
else if character = '"':
    invert inQuotes
else if character = ',' and not inQuotes:
    yield result
    result = ""
else:
    result += character
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it with regex:

```
[^,"]+|"(?:[^"]|"")+"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Xcg794ZlwH2z-net)

Comment: According to [the CSV standard](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) the back slash does not have a special meaning in CSV. Quotes inside quotes are to be escaped by duplication.

Comment: This doesn't account for unmatched quotes and also doesn't return empty find if you have an empty value `test,,test2`. You could change it to `[^,"]*|"(?:[^"]|"")*"` but that gives you empty matches even if there is a match (regex perk).

Comment: Thanks @Heinzi, changed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regular expressions for this task, the following should work:

```
(\S+,)\d+,\"(\d+),\S+\"
```

`(\S+,)` is a first capturing group that selects the first key, including the comma. This is followed by some numbers, a comma and a quote `\d+,\"`. The second capturing group `(\d+)` selects the second value, which is followed by a comma, a string and a quote: `,\D+\"`

But as others already wrote, there other solutions that don't involve regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*?)\,.*?\"(.*?)\,.*
```

You can try this.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rI6jZ0/2